# PHP : Rename keys of associative array to the value of a child element when given the childs key name

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

Is there a PHP function I've missed that will change the keys of the parent array when given the key name of its child(associative array) or is there at least an alternative to a foreach loop which i am using at the moment to change the keys.

Example array

```
    $arr = array( 
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'one',
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'two',
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'three',
        ) 
    );
```

I would like it to work like so..

```
$arr_name = array_change_key($arr,'name');
print_r($arr_name);
$arr_name => array( 
        'one', => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'one',
        ),
        'two' => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'two',
        ),
        'three' => array(
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'three',
        ) 
    );
//$arr is unchanged
```

This is just an added extra (not sure if possible)

```
array_change_key($arr,'name');
print_r($arr);

//$arr has changed because it doesn't have a variable to set 
$arr => array( 
        'one', => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'one',
        ),
        'two' => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'two',
        ),
        'three' => array(
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'three',
        ) 
    );

print_r($arr[0]); //undefined index
```

Comment: what array format you wish would the ouput be?

Comment: i have changed the question slightly, does this help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, something like:

```
$arr = array_combine(
    array_column($arr, 'name'),
    $arr
);
```

will use the `name` value from each record as the parent key, and give

```
array(3) {
  ["one"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "one"
  }
  ["two"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "two"
  }
  ["three"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "three"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to tell the function whether or not to "pass by reference" it has no way of knowing whether you are trying to set the returned result to a variable;

```
function array_change_key(array &$array, $key, $pass_by_reference = false){

    if($pass_by_reference){

       // check is_scalar($key)
       if(!is_scalar($key)) return FALSE; 
       // we already know isset($array), is_array($array) and isset(key) are true because $pass_by_reference is true;

        $array = markBakersAnswer($array,$key);

        return TRUE;
        //  pass-by-reference functions usually return true or false
    }
    return markBakersAnswer($array,$key);
}
```

[MarkBakersAnswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29365795/2273611) +1

```
$new_array = array_change_key($arr, 'name');        // $arr unchanged and $new_array == array with new keys
$new_array = array_change_key($arr, 'name', false); // $arr unchanged and $new_array == array with new keys

$new_array = array_change_key($arr, 'name', true);  // $arr changed (new keys),  $new_array = TRUE;
$new_array = array_change_key($arr, array(), true); // $arr changed (new keys),  $new_array = FALSE;
```